# SQL2000 - Replication - Publisher DB is removed but subscription still exists

Tags: sql-server-2000, publish-subscribe, replicate

I've tried to remove a replication between 2 databases on 2 different servers (both are SQL Server 2000).

The replication is completely removed from the publisher, however, the subscriber still has a link.  I don't know very much about replication, so I hope someone can help me out here...

- PUBLISHER has no traces
- SUBSCRIBER I find a subscription in the Enterprise Manager under REPLICATION\SUBSCRIPTIONS:
  [image: Subscriptions node]
- The line sais:
  [image: Subscription!]

If I run sp_dropsubscription on publisher site, it sais that the DB doesn't exist (which is correct since it was detached).
If I run sp_dropsubscription on subscriber site, I get 'The Publication  does not exist.

How can I remove this subscription?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to delete the subscription using the SQL Management studio (2008).